# Java cast based on the value of a field

Tags: java, reflection, casting, jackson

Is it possible to do a dynamic cast based on the value of some object field? For example. I have a class `User` that has a field `userType` which is of type `UserType` with possible values `CLIENT` and `DRIVER`. I have classes `Client` and `Driver` that extend from `User`. I would like to do a dynamic cast based on this field. I'd like something like this.

```
User user = userService.getById(id);

// returns Client if userType.equals(UserType.CLIENT)
// returns Driver if userType.equals(UserType.DRIVER)
return user.dynamicCast(user.getUserType());
```

Basically, I'd need something like `Jackson's` subtype, but I just need to invoke it manually from my code. This is how Jackson works:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
        property = "userType", 
        visible = true, 
        defaultImpl = InvalidUser.class)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Client.class, name = "CLIENT"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Driver.class, name = "DRIVER")
})
public abstract class User { /* ... */ }
```

Is something like that possible to dynamically invoke from code? I want something like that to avoid the `instanceof` checks.

### EDIT

This is the code I'm trying to avoid. Adding `toDto` is not possible to add the `User` class because it comes from another project layer as a gradle dependency. Business layer is not visible from the Transfer layer, but Transfer layer IS visible from the Business layer.

```
public UserDto readByEmail(String email) {
    User user = userService.findByEmail(email);

    switch (user.getUserType()) {
    case DRIVER:
        return new DriverDto((Driver) user);
    case CLIENT:
        return new ClientDto((Client) user);
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown type.");
    }
}
```

Instead of this, I'd like to have a cast based on the field.

Comment: What effective would you expect the cast to achieve? It can't change the declared return type of the method...

Comment: Of course, but it can change the actual object being returned. I want to save the object - specific fields, and not only have the fields from the base object returned.

Comment: No it can't. A cast between class types never changes the actual type of the object. Please edit your question to explain what you're really trying to achieve, and why you think a cast will help.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, so the acutal "view" on the object. I am sending it out as a JSON, and I want that JSON to have a Driver / Client specific fields what cast would allow.

Comment: @wesleyy Maybe you should post a piece of code of how would you like it to look like.

Comment: Then it sounds like you should have a `toJson` method or similar instead, that returns the appropriate view. The return type of the method determines the "view" of the returned object, and the object itself can't change type - so a cast really wouldn't help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please see my update. toJson is not possible, DTO layer is not visible from the business layer of my application...

Comment: It sounds like the code you're trying to avoid is exactly the code you should use.

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to avoid it because of scaling problems when number of possible user type increases. I can't have 10 instanceof in that method, it would be much better if I can just cast it based on the base-type field.

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't use instanceof at all. It switches and casts. Is it hugely pleasant having 10 casts? Nope... But it will work absolutely fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet The question was never will it work. The question was is there a way to do a field-based cast.

Comment: And the answer is "no, and it wouldn't help anyway, use a different approach. The code you've shown should work fine."

Comment: (Also note that even if the cast were feasible, you'd *still* need the switch statement in order to know whether to create an instance of `DriverDto`, `ClientDto` etc. All you'd be saving is the cast.)

Comment: Jackson provides [JsonView](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) for what you comment you want to achieve. No casting required